# Weights on a binary tree

Tags: optimization, computer-science

**If for a given [binary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree):**

- Every node with 2 children has a weight of **3**
- Every node with only 1 child has a weight of **2**
- Every node with no children (a leaf) has a weight of **1**
- The weight of a binary tree is the sum of all its nodes' weights

**For example, the weight of this binary tree is 11:**

[image: example]

> **If $n$ is the number of nodes in the tree, what is the maximum and minimum weight of a binary tree?**

(Answer in terms of $n$)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The weight is always $2 \times n -1$

Explanation

> First let's see what the weight of a node is.
>  The weight of a node is the number of edges that connect to that node except for the root node where it is the number of edges plus 1.
>  Let's take it one by one to prove.
>  Proof for non root nodes.
>  a leaf node has only one edge...the one to the parent. so weight 1.
>  a node with 1 child has 2 edges. The one to the child and the one to the parent.
>  a node with 2 children has 3 edges. 2 for the children and one for the parent.
>  a root node with 2 children has 2 edges and the weight of 3 so edges + 1
>  a root node with 1 child  has 1 edge and weight of 2 so edges +1
>  a root node with no children (a tree with 1 node) has the weight of 1. so edges + 1.

Now: .

> since there are n-1 edges in a tree with n nodes and each edge is counted twice in the tree (once for each node) and since there is only one root node the total weight is $ 2 \times (n - 1) + 1 = 2 \times n - 1$

Extra mile:

> Showing that there are n-1 edges in a binary tree.
>  a tree with 1 node has 0 edges. so this checks out.
>  a tree with 2 nodes has 1 edge. so it checks out.
>  a tree with n nodes means adding a new node to a tree with n-1 nodes (which has n-2 edges).  Adding one more node means adding one more edge because you have to link the new node to an existing node. So on more node means one more edge.

Comment: You got it exactly right! This is the reasoning I had in mind: rot13(Jura lbh nqq n abqr (nf n yrns), gur cnerag'f inyhr vapernfrf ol 1 naq gur yrns lbh nqq unf n jrvtug bs 1, fb lbh nqq 2 sbe rirel nqqrq abqr. N gerr bs 1 abqr unf n jrvtug bs 1 fvapr vg vf n yrns. Gurersber, gur jrvtug sbe n gerr bs a abqrf vf 2a-1 (2a fvapr vg'f 2 sbe rirel nqqvgvbany abqr, naq -1 gb svg gur onfr pnfr bs jrvtug(a=1) = 1.)

Answer (score 7):

The min and max are

> both $2n-1$

Proof:

> Each node has a base weight of 1, plus 1 extra weight for each child. This means each node contributes 1 extra weight to its parent, except the root which doesn't have a parent. With $n$ nodes, this means total $n$ base weight and $n-1$ total extra weight, for $2n-1$ over all.

Answer (score 2):

A tree graph $(V,E)$ has the property that  the number of edges is one less than the number of vertices ($|E|=|V|-1$). The [handshaking lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma) also tells you that $2|E|=\sum_{v\in V} d(v)$.

If you

> add a single extra node with weight 1 to the root of the tree with one edge, then you get a new graph $(V',E')$ in which the weight of each node is the same as its degree. So the sum of the weights $W$ we are looking for is
>   $$W= -1 + \sum_{v\in V'} W(v) = -1 + \sum_{v\in V'} d(v) = 2|E'|-1 = 2(|V'|-1)-1 = 2n-1$$

Answer (score 2):

> This is just the sum of degrees of a connected tree. The fact that you specified the tree to be binary is only relevant in one aspect; the root node is arbitrarily given an extra weight. A connected tree of $N$ nodes has $N-1$ edges, and the sum of degrees of any graph is always twice the number of edges. So the total weight is $2N-2$, plus the arbitrary extra 1 for the root node, giving a total of $2N-1$.

Comment: Good answer. Although, I'm not convinced that the binary nature of the tree factors in at all - you could have an N-ary tree with node weight equal to the number of children + 1, and the result would still come out the same. The extra 1 for the root node comes in because it's the only node where the weight is equal to one *more* than the node degree, but that's true regardless of how many children each node can have.

Answer (score 2):

> `2n - 1` for n >= 1

Reason:

> Every node has an initial value of 1 and adds 1 to the value of its parent, except
>  the root node which has no parent which gives the `- 1`

Answer (score 1):

To add on to what's already been said, the problem can be generalized for each node having a weight $k + \{\text{# of children}\}$ and for trees that are not binary:

> $\text{weight(k,n)} = (k+1)n - 1 = kn+n-1$
>
>  The $(k+1)n$ is because every node has a base value of $k$ and every additional child has a value of $1$, so adding a node as a leaf increases the parent's value by $1$ and the leaf's value is $k$.
>
>  The weight of any given tree must be $(k+1)n + c$ where $c$ is a constant since we know that every node adds $(k+1)n$ to the weight.
>
>  A tree with only 1 node has a value of $k$, so we have $(k+1)1 + c = k$ and therefore $c = -1$.
>
>  The fact that a node increases the parent's weight by 1 and adds it's base value does not apply only to binary trees, so this formula will work for ternary trees and n-ary trees as well.

To apply this to the original problem,

> Use $k = 1$ to get $\text{weight(n)} = 2n - 1$

Answer (score 0):

This feels like a homework problem, but the minimum weight would be:

> n

Given the case:

> n=1, the binary tree would be S the singleton set, so just a leaf with a weight of 1. When n=1 the weight is always 1, so minimum weight is n.

The maximum weight would be:

> 2n-1

Given the fact that:

> Binary trees are recursive, shown in the format of Left, Singleton, Right, so we can break any binary tree down to an n-size of 1 (L and R are empty sets, plus the Singleton set), 2 (Either L or R is an empty set, but not both), or 3 (Neither L nor R are empty sets). From this, when n is 1 we've shown that max weight is n (Which is also 2n-1 for this specific case). When n is 2 it must be a node with a single child, so weight is 2+1=3 (2n-1). When n is 3 it's a node with two children, each are a leaf, so 3+1+1 (also 2n-1).
>  Due to the recursive nature of Binary Trees, this can be propagated up to any value of n.

Comment: For maximum, it is correct, although rot13(gur zvavzhz inyhr vf bayl a va gur pnfr jurer a vf bar. Naq va gung pnfr vg vf nyfb 2a-1.)

Comment: The explanation for minimum weight is not really OK. the fact that the numbers check out in your example is just a coincidence.

Comment: Using your explanation you can say that the minimum is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$. It still matches.

Comment: This is not a homework problem, although I understand why you think that. I'm a third year CS student and some first year students taking Data Structures have been asking me for help studying. I felt that some of the problems they had felt much more like puzzles than homework, so I figured I could use it for inspiration. Many problems require more knowledge of DS concepts and I don't think those would belong here, but I felt that if I used only the concept of trees, it would be easily understandable to the community here and fun to some. Thanks for the feedback, though.

Comment: Right, I realized as I was writing out the explanation that the value was the same, just unique because of that particular case. Just forgot to change the initial value I stated.